# Low weeping acer without leaves on top branches

Tags: tree-care

My weeping acer is bald on the top branches, has been full of leaves until last year when there were fewer leaves, but this year hardly any on top. Weeping acer

Comment: can you post a picture and tell us what part of the world you live in?

Comment: Please also say how long you have had the plant and whether it's in the ground or a pot.

Comment: I live in the north of England, Acer is in the ground planted on a small raised bed, It has been full of leaves for last 14 years spread across 2 metres, very low growing